# Load HTML file and display in Flutter Web

Tags: flutter-web

I have a single HTML file that contains some JS functions and CSS styling.

Is it possible to load my html file into an embedded widget on Flutter Web? I've successfully accomplished this on iOS and Android using the flutter_webview pacakge, but haven't found a solution for Flutter Web.

Answer (score 9):

There is a `HTMLElementView` [widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/HtmlElementView-class.html) which can help you embed Html in flutter web. This widget can take an Iframe and render it. If you don't prefer Iframe then you can embed simply a `BodyElement` from the `dart:html` library directly.

An example of embedding Iframe is availabel [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/examples/html_platform_view/lib/main.dart). Eventhough its from an old repo, the code is valid and I couldn't find a latest one.

If you don't want do go the tough way, there is simplified widget from Rodydavis which is available [here](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_web_view) called easy_web_view.

Still if you need code sample a create simple dart pad and share the MRE, I will try to help. :)

Comment: I would like to try your answer, can you please provide an example?

Comment: The link for "example of embedding Iframe" is broken! =/

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find the latest example quickly. I Will update it when I find one.

Comment: Unfortunately easy_web_view has a large list of dependencies, including video, audio, etc. It's something to consider before using it.

Comment: Couldn't find HTMLElementView, but HtmlElementView works well.

Answer (score 6):

For the Iframe example, you can do something like this

**First, import 'ui' library, and 'html' library.**

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:html';
```

**Second, register your 'Iframe' with viewType 'test-view-type' just for example.**

```dart
ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
    'test-view-type',
    (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
      ..width = '640'
      ..height = '360'
      ..src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/5VbAwhBBHsg"
      ..style.border = 'none');
```

**Note:** you will notice that the compiler can't find `platformViewRegistry` method but it's okay if you choose to `Debug anyway` and it will run correctly without any problems.

**Finally, use `HtmlElementView` widget to run this Iframe**

```dart
return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
  children: [
    Text('Testing Iframe with Flutter'),
    HtmlElementView(viewType: 'test-view-type'),
  ],
));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this package [flutter_widget_from_html](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_widget_from_html) 
While defining the widget you need to set `webView: true` to get iFrame support

I just tested and it is working fine on web, and this package supports local assets too

Comment: thank u wroking in chrome