# load local html file to flutter web.Add local htm to flutter web project

Tags: flutter

I have a local HTML page that I want to add to my Flutter web app. How can I add a local HTML file to my Flutter web app? Is there a widget that I can use for this? How can I implement this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load HTML file and display in Flutter Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60731869/load-html-file-and-display-in-flutter-web)